# Extremely basic partial differentiation notation question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Please link to any duplicates if you're better at searching than I am

I have just started learning multivariable calculus. If $f(x,y)$ is a function, $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_y $ is the partial derivative of $f$ wrt $x$ with $y$ fixed. My textbook emphasises how important it is to write which variables are being fixed. However, pretty soon after when considering successive derivatives, this is dropped entirely. For example, it would write things like.

$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-P\implies\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial T\partial V}=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T+T\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial T \partial V}-\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$$

(The twice-derivatives have no indication what is fixed. These are the standard thermodynamic variables if more context is needed. I don't even know what you need to understand this scenario, please let me know if I've missed anything out. I am already aware that the order of differentiation doesnt matter, so perhaps this has some impact)

I would like to know why no indication of which variables are being fixed is given when differentiating more than once. As I understand it, the partials are still multivariable functions themselves. Is it the author being lazy or am I being entirely dimwitted and it doesn't even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions only depend on two variables $V$ and $T$ so if you derive twice neither is fixed.
More generally, the fixed variable is emphasized in the context of thermodynamics because in that field, there are various couples of variables that are being used (Clapeyron, Amagat...).
But as rule, in mathematics the fixed variables are not specified, since the only interesting variable is that which is not fixed.

Comment: Not specifying what is fixed makes sense to me when there are two independent variables as there is no ambiguity, but what about when there are three (or more) independent variables? By default am I just fixing everything except the two I'm interested in? For example if I have f(x,y,z), I could have(correct me if im wrong) $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{y,z} $ or just $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{y} $.

Comment: When you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, every other variable is fixed so only $x$ is relevant, and it is in fact useless to specify the other variables. It is in fact never done except in thermodynamics because there you want to specify what particular variables are used to describe the sytem (P,V) or (T,S) etc.

Comment: you might want to look at [link] https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148724/total-and-partial-derivatives-in-thermodynamics-and-maxwell-relations